# Deleting parent and all children from one MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a simple categories table, with one level nesting.

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(200)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| parent_id  | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | 0                   |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I would like to prepare eloqient query, which will delete category by ID. If child category provided - remove it. But if root category provided, remove it with all children.

I have something like this:

```
\DB::table('categories AS c1')->whereIn('c1.id', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->select('c2.id')
            ->from('categories AS c2')
            ->whereNull('c2.deleted_at')
            ->where('c2.parent_id', $id);
    })
    ->orWhere('c1.id', $id)
    ->delete();
```

But I cannot get it working. I am getting following error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `c1` where `c1`.`id` in 
(select `c2`.`id` from `categories` as `c2` where `c2' at line 1 (SQL: delete from
`categories` as `c1` where `c1`.`id` in (select `c2`.`id` from `categories` as `c2` where
`c2`.`deleted_at` is null and `c2`.`parent_id` = 15) or `c1`.`id` = 15)
```

How can I improve my query to get it working?

Comment: Are there only two layers (parent and children) or is it also possible that a children can be himself a parent for some other entry?
By the way: Your code is no Eloquent query, it's only using the Query Builder. Is there an Eloquent model for this table available?

Comment: Only two layers: roots and one level of children.
Yes, Eloquent model is available.

Comment: Yes, Eloquent model is available. I was trying both ways: Query Builder and Eloqient Model as well, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't something like `Category::where('id', $id)->orWhere('parent_id', $id)->delete()` work?

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. Unnecessarily I was looking for a over-complicated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to remove items with **id equal to $id** or **parent_id equal to $id**, the following could in theory work:

```
DB::table('categories')->where('id', $id)->orWhere('parent_id', $id)->delete();
```

In real life you probably have a foreign key constraint set on **parent_id** field that will prevent removing the parent category as long as children exist. If it is the case, you have 2 options:

1. Run 2 queries:

   DB::table('categories')->where('parent_id', $id)->delete();
   DB::table('categories')->where('id', $id)->delete();
2. When defining the constraint, set **ON DELETE** behaviour to **CASCADE**. This way, when parent is deleted, all its children will get deleted too. You can do this in migration file when defining the foreign key constraint

   ```
   Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
   });
   ```

Comment: My categories table is very simple, with less than 30 entries. There are also no constraints, so the first solution worked like a charm. Unnecessarily I was looking for a complicated solution, for such a simple task. Thank you.

Comment: how to do this in delete SQL satatement